# Use .htaccess to redirect 2 directories to https, and all others back to http

Tags: .htaccess, https

I've been able to find related answers to my problem, but mine combines a couple of the issues (multiple directories and redirection back to http), and I'm not sure how to best proceed.

I have 2 directories that need to be forced to https, but as soon as the user leaves those directories, they need to be redirected back to http.

Currently, I'm using this code to redirect the right folders to https.

```
  RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} careers
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://70.39.248.80/$1 [R,L]

  RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} career_management
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://70.39.248.80/$1 [R,L]
```

How could I edit that to redirect everything else back?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off  # HTTPS is off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(careers|career_management)  # needed directories
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://70.39.248.80/$1 [R,L]  # redirect to HTTPS

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on  # HTTPS is on, but it shouldn't
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://70.39.248.80/$1 [R,L]  # redirect to HTTP
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!  For some reason, when I include that code, it gives me an Internal Server Error.  I did change the IP address to my development web address: dev.mysite.com.  Not sure how to troubleshoot that. Any clues on where to start?